# Use XSLT to mark up text matching regex?

Tags: xml, xslt, unicode, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am trying to use XSLT 2.0 (Saxon-PE 9.6) on an HTML document to create tags that surround all contiguous runs of characters from a specified non-Latin Unicode block (spaces allowed). I need to apply this process to every text() node in the document. I have made some progress with two approaches that use `<xsl:analyze-string>` and using `fn:replace()` but I've not been able to arrive at a satisfactory and complete solution.

For example, here is some text containing Hindi:

Input: `<p>चाय का कप means ‘cup of tea’ in हिन्दि.</p>`

Desired Output: `<p><span xml:lang="hi-Deva">चाय का कप</span> means ‘cup of tea’ in <span xml:lang="hi-Deva">हिन्दि</span>.</p>`

How can this process be implemented in XSLT 2.0?

---

Here's my attempt with `<xsl:analyze-string>`:

(Note: the Hindi language uses the Devanagari code block U+0900 to U+097F.)

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="textValue" select="."/>

  <xsl:analyze-string select="$textValue" regex="(\s*.*?)([&#x0900;-&#x097f;]+)((\s+[&#x0900;-&#x097f;]+)*)(\s*.*)">

    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
      <span xml:lang="hi-Deva"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/></span>
      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(5)"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>

    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="$textValue"/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>

  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

On the test input, this produces:
`<p><span xml:lang="hi-Deva">चाय का कप</span> means ‘cup of tea’ in हिन्दि.</p>` This approach misses the second region of Hindi text (हिन्दि). I need an approach that will find and tag all occurrences matched by the regex.

My second approach used `fn:replace()`:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select='fn:replace(., "[&#x0900;-&#x097f;]+(\s+[&#x0900;-&#x097f;]+)*", "xxx$0xxx")'/>
</xsl:template>
```

On the test input this produces: `<p>xxxचाय का कपxxx means ‘cup of tea’ in xxxहिन्दिxxx.</p>` This is clearly incorrect, since the Hindi is wrapped in xxx’s, not span tags, but on the positive side, each region of Hindi is in fact discovered and processed. I cannot replace the xxx code with span tags because that is invalid XSLT.

Comment: The regex you're using in the first (analyze-string) approach matches the _entire_ input string in one go, so you'll just get the matching-substring block firing once. Instead, you want a regex that matches just a single Hindi segment, then the matching-substring will fire for Hindi and the non-matching-substring for non-hindi segments.

Comment: Regarding the first regex, all of the xsl:analyze-string examples I found in my searches matched against the whole line. I also did not find documentation that describes its behavior for multiple matches. In my xsl:analyze-string experiments, I thought I tried the exact regex used in your solution below but apparently I made some other error that obscured the results.

Comment: I found the exact language in the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-analyze-string: "Having found the first match, the instruction proceeds to find the second and subsequent matches by repeating the search, starting at the first character that was not included in the previous match."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came up with http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMo which just does

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([&#x0900;-&#x097f;]+)((\s+[&#x0900;-&#x097f;]+)*)">

    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <span xml:lang="hi-Deva"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    </xsl:matching-substring>

    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>

  </xsl:analyze-string>       
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Accepted answer because of complete solution and use of <xsl:value-of select="."/> in <xsl:matching-substring>.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the previous answers, you might like to note that you can write `\p{IsDevanagari}` in place of `[&#x0900;-&#x097f;]`

Answer (score 1):

This should work (some comments after the code):

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$textValue" regex="([&#x0900;-&#x097f;]+)((\s+[&#x0900;-&#x097f;]+)*)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
          <span xml:lang="hi-Deva"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></span>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

- the regex is the one from your second try (as it was correctly matching only the Hindi text fragments!), just with parentheses around the first part
- the `matching-substring` branch puts the `span` around the Hindi text
- the `non-matching-substring` branch just returns the unmodified "normal" text substring (you were returning the whole text!)